# TouchId Authentication -Remove alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, touch-id

When I am adding touch ID authentication on first screen itself it is having an alert view with 
**"TouchId for Your app name -Local message- Enter Password-Cancel"**
How can I remove this alert view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS cancel TouchID authentication dialog programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276412/ios-cancel-touchid-authentication-dialog-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't remove this Alert!

Comment: we can remove local message - enter password - cancel. But i want to remove the entire alert :( :( :(

Comment: @Mee any luck? I need to hide the alert and provide my own view.

Answer (score 1):

**From iOS 9**, Apple provides API to remove default authentication alert popup. For that we just need to invalidate existing LAContext policy.

> authenticationContext.invalidate()

**Notes:-**

- Invalidation terminates any existing policy evaluation and the respective call will fail with LAErrorAppCancel.
- After the context has been invalidated, it can not be used for policy evaluation and an attempt to do so will fail with LAErrorInvalidContext.
- Invalidating a context that has been already invalidated has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code for removed alert FingerPrint view

```
Context.invalidate()
Context = nil
```